# How can I compile a script that has some dynamic code?

Tags: dynamic, compilation, interpreter, jit, red

I want to compile this script:

```
Red [File: %b.red]
context [
    a: 123
    hidden: 999
    set 'global-exports context [
        export-a: a
    ]
]
probe global-exports
```

But I get an error when trying to compile it with `$ ./red-13oct19-a4ee537c -r b.red`:

```
*** Red Compiler Internal Error: Script Error : Invalid path value: global-exports 
*** Where: register-object 
*** Near:  [objects/context/global-exports: make object! [
a: none
hidden: none
]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can wrap dynamic code with `do [...]` function, which treats a block of code like data and uses an interpreter to launch it at runtime:

```
Red [File: %b.red]
context [
    a: 123
    hidden: 999
    do [   ;-- the code inside is run by interpreter at runtime
        set 'global-exports context [
            export-a: a
        ]
    ]
]
probe get 'global-exports   ;-- dynamic retrieval
```

You also have to retrieve values dynamically, unless you initialize it statically (e.g. `global-exports: none`) somewhere earlier.

In this particular case also exchanging `context` with `make object!` will be sufficient:

```
Red [File: %b.red]
context [
    a: 123
    hidden: 999
    set 'global-exports make object! [
        export-a: a
    ]
]
probe global-exports
```

Compiling dynamic code [will be possible with JIT compiler](https://github.com/red/red/issues/924#issuecomment-55394824), which is planned in future, but not before Red version 1.0.

(thanks @9214 and @hiiamboris for the ideas [on red/help gitter chat](https://gitter.im/red/help?at=5da6d96639d0c70757bb4447))